# how to insert .csv data in oracle table

Tags: r, oracle

here we can read the data with the read.csv function in R

```
 > mydata = read.csv("mydata.csv")  
 > mydata                           
    Col1 Col2 Col3 
 1  100   a1   b1 
 2  200   a2   b2 
 3  300   a3   b3
```

but my problem is how to insert .csv data in oracle table using R programing.any one can me suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Why do that? Use [External Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm#i1007478).  You can then use SQL to manipulate the csv data.

EDIT:

Here's a simple tutorial: http://orafaq.com/node/848

Comment: any one example for explanation i am new in r programing